# How to tag different missing data in R

Tags: r, tags, na, missing-data

I'm so glad I found the `sjlabelled` package to set NA labels with data (comparable to Stata). My missings are coded as negative numbers. The behaviour of `print_tagged_na` is to only display one digit of the original missings. So when I convert "-2" to "not applicable" and "-3" to "not valid", I cannot distinguish the missings in the output of `print_tagged_na` since it only displays a minus sign.

Here I adjusted the MWE from the package description.

```
library(sjlabelled)
library(haven)

# test data
dummy <- sample(5:-5, 100, replace=TRUE)
# try to label "pos." and "neg." missings
dummy <- set_na(dummy, na = c("Refused" = 5), as.tag = TRUE)
print_tagged_na(dummy)
dummy <- set_na(dummy, na = c("Not applicable" = -1), as.tag = TRUE)
dummy <- set_na(dummy, na = c("Not valid" = -2), as.tag = TRUE)
# NA(5) is displayed, -1 and -2 become NA(-)
print_tagged_na(dummy)
```

[image]

How can I change this behavior? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found an answer. I directly substituted negative numbers with letters via `tagged_na`. Here we should only use single letters, since "not applicable" or "not valid" will again be displayed as "NA(n)". Hope that others will benefit.

```
# create data
dummy <- sample(5:-5, 100, replace=TRUE)
dummy
# set 5 to tagged NA (working)
dummy <- set_na(dummy, na = c("Refused" = 5), as.tag = TRUE)
print_tagged_na(dummy)
# set negative numbers by tagged NA (working)
dummy[dummy=="-1"]<-tagged_na("a")
dummy[dummy=="-2"]<-tagged_na("b")
print_tagged_na(dummy)
```

[image]